# Why is there a massive "ghost" google + button on my (unfinished) site?

Tags: html

Okay, so I and some other people are build a site in webplus X5, and when we open the html in IE 10 (Chrome seems to not be opening lately, but thats another problem) we get this:

[image]

And, this is what that page is in webplus.

[image]

HTML code as follows:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta name="Generator" content="Serif WebPlus X5">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8">
<title>Home</title>
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<style type="text/css">
body {margin: 0px; padding: 0px;}
.Artistic-Body-C
{
    font-family:"Arial Black", sans-serif; font-weight:700; text-decoration:underline; font-size:54.0px; line-height:1.41em;
}
.Artistic-Body-C-C0
{
    font-family:"Arial Black", sans-serif; font-weight:700; font-size:54.0px; line-height:1.41em;
}
.Artistic-Body-C-C1
{
    font-family:"Arial Black", sans-serif; font-weight:700; text-decoration:underline; font-size:32.0px; line-height:1.41em;
}
.Body-C
{
    font-family:"Arial Black", sans-serif; font-size:27.0px; line-height:1.41em;
}
.Body-C-C0
{
    font-family:"Arial Black", sans-serif; font-size:15.0px; line-height:1.47em;
}
.Artistic-Body-C-C2
{
    font-family:"Arial Black", sans-serif; color:#ffffff; font-size:19.0px; line-height:1.42em;
}
.Body-C-C1
{
    font-family:"Arial Black", sans-serif; color:#ffffff; font-size:16.0px; line-height:1.44em;
}
.Button1,.Button1:link,.Button1:visited{text-decoration:none;display:block;position:absolute;background-color:transparent;}
.Button1:focus{outline-style:none;}
.Button1 span,.Button1:link span,.Button1:visited span{color:#000000;font-family:"Arial Black",sans-serif;font-weight:normal;text-decoration:none;text-align:center;text-transform:none;font-style:normal;left:0px;top:0px;width:107px;height:20px;font-size:16px;display:block;position:absolute;cursor:pointer;}
.Button2,.Button2:link,.Button2:visited{text-decoration:none;display:block;position:absolute;background-color:transparent;}
.Button2:focus{outline-style:none;}
.Button2 span,.Button2:link span,.Button2:visited span{color:#5c7e13;font-family:"Arial Black",sans-serif;font-weight:normal;text-decoration:none;text-align:center;text-transform:none;font-style:normal;left:0px;top:0px;width:107px;height:20px;font-size:16px;display:block;position:absolute;cursor:pointer;}
.Button2:hover span{color:#000000;}
.Button2:active span{color:#000000;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="wpscripts/jspngfix.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="wpscripts/wpstyles.css" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript">var blankSrc = "wpscripts/blank.gif";
</script>
</head>

<body text="#000000" style="background-color:#ffffff; text-align:center; height:900px;">
<div style="background-color:transparent;text-align:left;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;position:relative;width:1440px;height:900px;">
<img src="wpimages/wp817e53a4_06.png" width="1440" height="900" border="0" alt="" onload="OnLoadPngFix()" style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;">
<img src="wpimages/wpc73afde9_06.png" width="202" height="193" border="0" alt="" onload="OnLoadPngFix()" style="position:absolute;left:15px;top:13px;">
<div style="position:absolute;left:270px;top:17px;width:649px;height:76px;">
    <div class="Wp-Artistic-Body-P">
        <span class="Artistic-Body-C">S.N.A.K.E.S</span><span class="Artistic-Body-C-C0"> &nbsp;</span><span class="Artistic-Body-C-C1">Animal shelter</span></div>
</div>
<div id="txt_1" style="position:absolute;left:250px;top:202px;width:937px;height:590px;overflow:hidden;">
<p class="Wp-Body-P"><span class="Body-C">Here at S.N.A.K.E.S, (Serpent National Anti-Kruelty* Eviromental Shelter) we care
    for those that are not typically considered as pets, in the form of snakes! Our slithery
    friends are not what those that are faint-hearted consider pets, but those adventurous
    souls out there may happily adopt on of our various serpents. Those people can look
    here to donate and look at these snakes, as well as contact us, and apply to volunteer
    as a snake carer.</span></p>
<p class="Wp-Body-P"><span class="Body-C">-To navigate, use the links on the left. Click the logo or the home button to return
    here. There is various images along the<img src="wpimages/wp2f8a775f_06.png" width="920" height="900" border="0" onload="OnLoadPngFix()" title="" alt="" style="display:block;position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;"> right: they are just images or funny snake-things
    we have found.</span></p>
<p class="Wp-Body-P"><span class="Body-C-C0"><br></span></p>
<p class="Wp-Body-P"><span class="Body-C-C0">*Kruelty is spelt wrong on purpose, to allow the name to work.</span></p>
</div>
<img src="wpimages/wp82934362_05_06.jpg" width="265" height="166" border="0" alt="" style="position:absolute;left:1175px;top:0px;">
<form id="site_search_1" action="" onSubmit="return false;" style="position: absolute; top:212px; left:0px; width:250px; height:22px;margin: 0; padding: 0;">
    <input id="site_search_1_input" name="site_search_1_input" onkeypress="if (event.keyCode==13) window.location.href='page4.html?site_search_results_1='+document.getElementById('site_search_1_input').value+'&amp;depth=0';" style="width: 107px;" type="text"><div style="display: inline"><button onclick="window.location.href='page4.html?site_search_results_1='+document.getElementById('site_search_1_input').value+'&amp;depth=0';" style="width: 133px;">Search this site!</button></div>
</form>
<img src="wpimages/wpa7694a4a.gif" width="267" height="151" border="0" alt="" style="position:absolute;left:1173px;top:166px;">
<img src="wpimages/wpccc61754_06.png" width="98" height="38" border="0" title="" alt="Home" onload="OnLoadPngFix()" style="position:absolute;left:251px;top:169px;">
<div style="position:absolute;left:267px;top:90px;width:601px;height:73px; background-image:url('wpimages/wpaff7835e_06.png');">
    <a href="home page.html" id="nav_31_B1" class="Button1" style="display:block;position:absolute;left:13px;top:27px;width:107px;height:20px;"><span>Home</span></a>
    <a href="page3.html" id="nav_31_B2" class="Button2" style="display:block;position:absolute;left:130px;top:27px;width:107px;height:20px;"><span>Volunteer</span></a>
    <a href="page6.html" id="nav_31_B3" class="Button2" style="display:block;position:absolute;left:247px;top:27px;width:107px;height:20px;"><span>Donations</span></a>
    <a href="page10.html" id="nav_31_B4" class="Button2" style="display:block;position:absolute;left:364px;top:27px;width:107px;height:20px;"><span>Contact us</span></a>
    <a href="page9.html" id="nav_31_B5" class="Button2" style="display:block;position:absolute;left:481px;top:27px;width:107px;height:20px;"><span>Gallery</span></a>
</div>
<img src="wpimages/wp90a589a8_06.png" width="1440" height="101" border="0" alt="" onload="OnLoadPngFix()" style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:799px;">
<div style="position:absolute;left:7px;top:799px;width:185px;height:27px;">
    <div class="Wp-Artistic-Body-P">
        <span class="Artistic-Body-C-C2">Explore the site</span></div>
</div>
<map id="map0" name="map0">
    <area shape="rect" coords="212,6,335,26" href="page6.html" alt="">
    <area shape="rect" coords="86,5,206,25" href="page3.html" alt="">
    <area shape="rect" coords="1,4,67,28" href="home page.html" alt="">
</map>
<img src="wpimages/wp70aa4b65_06.png" width="339" height="27" border="0" title="" alt="Donations" onload="OnLoadPngFix()" usemap="#map0" style="position:absolute;left:8px;top:836px;">
<map id="map1" name="map1">
    <area shape="rect" coords="210,7,300,26" href="page9.html" alt="">
    <area shape="rect" coords="0,3,128,26" href="page10.html" alt="">
</map>
<img src="wpimages/wpd689eff4_06.png" width="302" height="27" border="0" title="" alt="Gallery" onload="OnLoadPngFix()" usemap="#map1" style="position:absolute;left:8px;top:863px;">
<a href="home page.html"><img src="wpimages/wp5533b116.gif" width="64" height="24" border="0" title="" alt="Home" style="position:absolute;left:9px;top:840px;"></a>
<img src="wpimages/wp8183884b_06.png" width="326" height="55" border="0" title="" alt="Share this site" onload="OnLoadPngFix()" style="position:absolute;left:479px;top:797px;">
<img src="wpimages/wp2ce0a75d_06.png" width="47" height="47" border="0" alt="" onload="OnLoadPngFix()" style="position:absolute;left:478px;top:853px;">
<img src="wpimages/wpb26f87b1_06.png" width="51" height="51" border="0" alt="" onload="OnLoadPngFix()" style="position:absolute;left:535px;top:849px;">
<img src="wpimages/wp2f8a775f_06.png" width="48" height="47" border="0" alt="" onload="OnLoadPngFix()" style="position:absolute;left:593px;top:853px;">
<img src="wpimages/wp007bb409_06.png" width="48" height="48" border="0" alt="" onload="OnLoadPngFix()" style="position:absolute;left:648px;top:852px;">
<div id="txt_37" style="position:absolute;left:950px;top:799px;width:490px;height:101px;overflow:hidden;">
<p class="Wp-Body-P"><span class="Body-C-C1">All images Copyrighted by their rightful owners. The SNAKES logo is copyrighted to
    SNAKES Animal shelter © 2015 The Facebook, Twitter, Google+ and Instagram logos are
    property of their relevant companies.</span></p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>​
```

(I Would add the 'webplus' tag, but there is not one :(

-EDITS-
Edit 1 - Since the ghost copy matches the dimensions of the original, i tried modifying th original. The result of this was a pixelated version of my problem.
-Edit 2- I have worked out it seems to be related to the text box. We don't know why, but that text seems to be causing it. Will tinker with it 16/10/15

Comment: Add code or JSFiddle. We can't help you if we have just images. Can you bake a cake with just the picture of it ?

Comment: without some javascript, html or css we can't help you

Comment: @Seblor You can if the ingredients list is in that picture :) Seriously though, ill add the html shortly.

Comment: Yes. But in your picture there aren't the ingredients (codes). :)

Comment: A lot of tools that claim to be WYSIWYG are iffy, particularly one several years old.

Comment: @TheDeveloper I know. give me one minute...

Comment: @AlexK. True, but I have Never, EVER, in my long bouts of craziness which Webplus, Have NEVER had this (sort) of problem.

Comment: Please, post wpscripts/jspngfix.js too.

Comment: @TheDeveloper will do tomorrow, watch this space at about 12:40 pm GMT.

Comment: @TheDeveloper I have worked out what is up. I have no idea why, but see the answer soon-to-appear below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so I know this is not a universal fix ( Or even a fix) but I found out that, for some bizarre reason, the text:

Here at S.N.A.K.E.S, (Serpent National Anti-Kruelty* Eviromental Shelter) we care
    for those that are not typically considered as pets, in the form of snakes! Our slithery
    friends are not what those that are faint-hearted consider pets, but those adventurous
    souls out there may happily adopt on of our various serpents. Those people can look
    here to donate and look at these snakes, as well as contact us, and apply to volunteer
    as a snake carer.

Plus The font, ariel black, plus the text size, makes it happen. upon removing and re-adding the text with a larger font, it disappeared! Yay, no more scaring people at 8.30 in the morning.